# Django: Casting Abstract Models

Tags: python, django

I have an abstract Django model that I use to create two other models. How can I avoid duplicating code when dealing with the different examples below (for example, when creating a Boxed cereal and a `Bowled` cereal I would like to avoid duplicating the function twice.

```
class Cereal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Boxed(Cereal):
    pass

class Bowled(Cereal):
    pass


func some_func_boxed(name):
    boxed = Boxed.objects.get(id=1)
    boxed.name = name
    boxed.save()

func some_func_bowled(name):
    bowled = Bowled.objects.get(id=1)
    bowled.name = name
    bowled.save()
```

Comment: Why do these functions (?) have a `name` parameter that you do not use?

Comment: doesn't look right. whats your intention? get data from a charfield or label it with a name? you are creating a charfield with ```name``` then replace it with string

Comment: @Piakkaa no, this is how Django works.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry, the function was a contrived example and I wasn't really thinking about it– was just writing something down quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def some_func(name, Instance):
    i = Instance.objects.get(id=1)
    i.name = "some name"
    i.save()
```

The good idea is using `strategy pattern`, article for example: https://medium.com/@sheikhsajid/design-patterns-in-python-part-1-the-strategy-pattern-54b24897233e

Answer (score 3):

You can add this as a `@classmethod` on the `Cereal` model:

```
class Cereal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

    @classmethod
    def some_func_cereal(cls, name):
        bowled = cls.objects.get(id=1)
        bowled.name = name
        bowled.save()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

You can then call this method with:

```
Boxed.some_func_cereal('Captain Crunch')
Bowled.some_func_cereal('Lucky Charms')
```

The class with which you call the class method, is passed as the `cls` parameter in the `some_func_cereal` function.

Answer (score 3):

You could add an update method to your Cereal absract class such as:

```py
    class Cereal:

        def update(self, **kwargs):
            for key, val in kwargs.items():
                setattr(self, key, val)
            self.save(update_fields=kwargs.keys())
            return self
```

and use it as follows to update any column you like

```py
    BoxedInstance.update(name="new name")

    or 

    BoxedInstance.update(name="new name", taste="cardboardy")
```